# Was the 1918 Wonder Woman photo from Dawn of Justice identical to that used in the Wonder Woman film?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, props, wonder-woman-2017

Did they have all the actors lined up for *Wonder Woman* at the time?

[image]

Is the photo identical or was it subtly modified between the two movies?

Was the scene meticulously recreated for *Wonder Woman*, or was set already constructed at the earlier time, or were the props and scenery stored and reused?

(Note, *Batman v. Superman* was filmed in 2014 and *Wonder Woman* was filmed in 2015 and 2016.)

Comment: Please provide a link/visual of the photos you are talking about

Comment: @Gallifreyan:   We were editting at the same time.   Reverted to yours.   I only google searched and didn't realize you actually took a screen cap so didn't see the advantage of one over the other.

Comment: Ah, well. Good then :)

Comment: Funny that I had the same question but I didn't bother to look it up until someone else asked...

Comment: Just wondering… how does the picture fit into BvS?  Is it a post-credit scene just to serve as a teaser, or is it actually in the story for some reason?

Comment: @JDługosz, it is very much in the story because Bruce Wayne gaining access to the photo ultimately leads to the initial contact between Batman and Wonder Woman.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, it's (probably) the same photo.

[According to this new article](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/story-behind-black-white-photo-linked-batman-v-superman-wonder-woman-222231036.html), the photo was the first thing done:

> “That was the first thing that we shot, before we’d even shot a scene [for Wonder Woman] we shot that photograph,” actor Ewen Bremner, who plays Charlie, told to Yahoo Movies.

*However*, the scene where the photo is "taken" in *Wonder Woman* had to be recreated later, based on that photo:

> “It meant that when we eventually got around to shooting the scene that the [photograph] is from, **we had to really painstakingly recreate it**,” Bremner continued. “Because we [took the photo] against a half-built set, in a way sets were still being built at that point. So by the time we came around to filming that scene, probably around five months later, the sets were much more developed. **So we had to find a way to recreate the exact same image after half a year had gone by.**”

Once the photo was created for *Wonder Woman*, it was transferred over to the *BvS* team. The screen Ben Affleck would have been staring at could easily have had the contents changed in post.

That master photo seems to be used for all scenes and materials that need it, such [*Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice, The Art of the Film*](https://youtu.be/7lN0N7W_yNE?t=7m23s). That book was published 2 days after the *BvS* was released. (If you look at the details around the edges, the photo in the book seems to more closely match the version in *Wonder Woman* than the one in *BvS*):
[image]

The photo itself was taken in November 2015. The live action scene recreating the photo was likely filmed in [December of 2015 when filming was in Lower Halstow, Kent, England](http://dccomicsmovie.com/wonder-woman-filming-in-lower-halstow-and-more-production-details/).

Seen here is the "original" physical version used at the beginning of *Wonder Woman*, and it appears to be identical in terms of actor positioning and angle.

[image]

Here's the full-view *BvS* frame:
[image]

As you can see, the photo is *mostly* the same. Bruce's file seems to be a cropped version of the full photo, and it has a different tint and level of contrast (probably from some sort of enhancement).

The "live" color version floating about is pretty close to the original, but they're at obviously different angles. Although, the interview with Bremner now makes it clear that it's not exactly the same set, but a recreation based on the photo.

[image]

While I still have no *hard* evidence, it certainly appears that a single master photo was used, but it was cropped and altered for the on-screen appearance in *BvS*. Rather than using a slightly different version of the photo, based on the full production filming, it seems that *Wonder Woman* kept the original pre-filming version for the screen.

Comment: Not necessarily (regarding the last paragraph) - he wasn't looking at a green screen for other computer sequences: https://youtu.be/DdW4xcLCdcY?t=2m2s

Comment: Good answer - just adding link to Official Trailer and a screen shot from the trailer.

Comment: @KerrAvon The image link was formatted wrong, and my edit accidentally overrode it anyway. However, I'm going to leave it _off_ right now, because the level of zoom in that trailer is different than what we see in the movie: IE, she actually holds the photo and it's not from straight on. So, the photo in the trailer could actually be from a different part of the movie, and adds to the confusion (for me).

Comment: Fair enough - just trying to help but whilst she does take the transparency out of the box from Bruce in the movie, there is a full frame shot as well. I'm sure as I watched the movie again on Tuesday.

Comment: @KerrAvon Yeah, and later in the movie when they take the actual one and transition to it. I just can't be 100% that it's the same asset all around, so the one in the OP question is good enough for me. Thanks, though!

Comment: @KerrAvon The transparency is in one of the trailers, too. I missed it looking before, but I've got a cap of that in here, now. Thought you might be interested.

Comment: @Gallifreyan A rectangular screen is relatively easy to edit in post. It's _really_ easy if you know the contents on a frame-by-frame basis. That's sometimes even easier if the background is solid green, but if it changes between (for example) green and blue, it's easier to not disappear a green shirt.

Comment: This is a great answer so far.   There's an aspect that's not really covered (perhaps not very clear from the question).   What would also be good is any explanation of whether the picture was actually taken around when the *Woman Woman* scenes were filmed, or whether this was posed early for *BvS*.   I.e. Even if it is the same picture, is the picture from the same time as the filming?    (Or was it effectively 'recreated' twice?)

Comment: The quality of the picture in the image which you have for the shot from Wonder Woman is too poor to be able to actually compare with the image from BvS detail for detail. The most obvious difference is that the one from BvS has the mouse pointer still over the image. Beyond that, there are a couple of details that look slightly different, but the quality of the photo, and angle of the photo within the image, makes it difficult to tell. Do you have a better, more detailed shot of the photo from Wonder Woman?

Comment: @Makyen I could probably get one by watching the trailer in 4K and grabbing the screen from that. I'm away from my PC until later, though

Comment: @ThePopMachine I haven't yet found anything to indicate that the photo _wasn't_ taken from WW's principal photography, but I also haven't found much about behind the scenes anyway. I'll try again later, but I may not have much luck until Blu-ray special features.

Comment: @ThePopMachine A new interview with one of the cast members came out that I think has more of the information you're looking for. I've updated my answer accordingly (including a link to the article)

Comment: @WebHead:   The new quote contradicts your previous text so you might want to update it.   New quote:  it was recreated 1/2 year later.  Old text: Photo taken in November and probably recreated in December.

Answer (score 7):

The black and white photo used for BvS and Wonder Woman (WW) prologue is probably the same. The colour version and the scene in the WW movie was however recreated. This was confirmed in [several interviews](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1669639/why-shooting-that-wonder-woman-photo-for-batman-v-superman-was-problematic-according-to-ewen-bremner) where the set had to be recreated 5 months after, to match the photo setting.

> It meant that when we eventually got around to shooting the scene that the [photograph] is from, we had to really painstakingly recreate it. Because we [took the photo] against a half-built set, in a way sets were still being built at that point. So by the time we came around to filming that scene, probably around five months later, the sets were much more developed. So we had to find a way to recreate the exact same image after half a year had gone by.

You will also note that in the colour version, WW sling strap on her chest (to attach the shield on her back), is stretching from her left right shoulder to the bottom right, whilst the BW picture is the other way around (it magically reversed!). Her hair is also messier in the BW picture!

Comment: Can you link those interviews?

Comment: Here you go the interview:http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1669639/why-shooting-that-wonder-woman-photo-for-batman-v-superman-was-problematic-according-to-ewen-bremner

Comment: Check out the sling strap, it is definitely reversed between the BW and colour version :)

Comment: Good job!   That's the missing piece!

Comment: Nice catch on that strap! Hopefully no one from the set notices that we noticed.